# How to make SimpleForm boolean fields display as radio_buttons by default?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, formbuilder

I'm using the Rails SimpleForm gem to create forms. I realize a boolean field named "accepts" (which typically displays as a checkbox) can be displayed as a pair of radio buttons instead, by changing

```
<%= f.input :accepts %>
```

to

```
<%= f.input :accepts, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

However, I am using a generic form template to dynamically generate a form for any Rails model in a loop like this:

```
<% some_rails_model.attribute_names.each |attr| %>
  <% f.input attr %>
<% end %>
```

Since I don't know whether a particular attribute is a boolean (as opposed to a string, integer, etc.), I don't know when to add `as: :radio_buttons`.

Is there a way to make ALL booleans default to being displayed as radio buttons?

Alternatively, is there some simple way to check whether `attr` is a boolean, so that I then know when to add `as: :radio_buttons`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which involves checking in the model whether a particular field is a boolean or not:

```
<% some_rails_model.attribute_names.each |attr| %>
  <% if some_rails_model.columns_hash[attr].type == :boolean %>
    <%= f.input attr, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.input attr %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```